# How to check currently running thread under given Task Executor with Spring @Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor, executor, spring-async

I am not creating bean explicitly. I am using `@EnableAsync` and spring properties.

```
spring.task.execution.pool.core-size=10
spring.task.execution.pool.max-size=20
spring.task.execution.pool.queue-capacity=50
spring.task.exection.thread-name-prefix=AsyncThread-
spring.task.exection.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.exection.shutdown.await-termination-period=300s

        

MyExecutor {
        
         @Asyc
         <T> void execute(List<T> list){
            //processing my data as list here
        }
    }
```

// class where I need to check currently running and available thread for given pool and then decide to break my list accordingly to available threads in pool.
Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

//list having 10K objects
List data;

int currentlyAvailableThread;

int maxAllowedListSize = data.size() / currentlyAvailableThread;

// execute logic for sublist ,
}

}